# Where should I place complex queries in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

So I've searched the internet for similar cases, and I just got lost from all contradicting answers, and unrelated scenarios. So I thought to put my case hoping to get some specific answers.

I am new to Laravel, and creating small application. In the application I have to search for offeres and show the result in a blade view. Since the query is complex, and output of the search does not belong to a specific Model, I just wish to keep it as a raw query.

I have placed the query in the controller, but I just don't feel it's the right place. Especially if I need to reuse the query in many places.

Here's the method from the OfferController:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $area =  $request->area;
    $size =  $request->size;

    $sql = "SELECT distinct product_name,product_offer.quantity, product_offer.price
            FROM product
            inner join brand on product.brand_id = brand.brand_id
            inner join brand_area on brand_area.brand_id = brand.brand_id
            inner join area on area.area_id = brand_area.area_id
            inner join product_offer on product_offer.product_id = product.product_id
            where area.area_id = :area
            and  product.size_id = :size ";

    $params = array(
        'area'=>$area,
        'size'=>$size
    );

    $offers = DB::select( DB::raw($sql), $params);

    return view('searchresult')->with($offers);

}
```

So in short: should I move the query to the model, create DAL class, or keep it here? Baring in mind the project is small scale.

Comment: You could move it to the model, but I suggest you use a Trait to do this. The reason why is that it will keep your code clean and you'll be able to reuse this code later for other uses. A Trait is mainly made for reusable code. To use it, you will be creating, only write: ```use MyCustomTrait``` in the scope of your PHP class. Here's a link to learn more about traits: https://www.develodesign.co.uk/news/laravel-traits-what-are-traits-and-how-to-create-a-laravel-trait/

Comment: I typically create service classes, which I then inject into my controller actions as required. This consolidates related logic, whilst also making it easily reusable.

Comment: The question you should be asking yourself is whether such a complex query should be in your code at all or should you re-write this as a model with relationships instead? The latter method allows you to spread your logic around to your models and write very simple queries which can go anywhere

Comment: @apokryfos how can I write complex models. I thought models represent entities or tables, not views.

Comment: The Model-View-Controller (MVC) pattern is intended to make use of the controller to retrieve models and return views that are rendered using data from the retrieved models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion, if you are going to reuse it, create a service that will perform that query and gives you back a result, something like `SearchService` that looks like this:

```
<?php

class SearchService
{

  public static function perform(array $params){
     $sql = "SELECT distinct product_name,product_offer.quantity, product_offer.price
            FROM product
            inner join brand on product.brand_id = brand.brand_id
            inner join brand_area on brand_area.brand_id = brand.brand_id
            inner join area on area.area_id = brand_area.area_id
            inner join product_offer on product_offer.product_id = product.product_id
            where area.area_id = :area
            and  product.size_id = :size ";

    return DB::select( DB::raw($sql), $params);
  }
}

?>
```

And by doing so, you can just call

```
SearchService::perform([...]);
```

to get the results.
Obviously this is version1.0, you can improve it in a lot of ways, for example making it not static in order to make it testable, and also to allow getter and setter to exists, and a lot of other things, that might be usefull

Comment: I agree with the use of a service, but wouldn't use static functions.

Comment: @fubar yes yes, i've infact added a note at the bottom to explicit that is the version1.0, and in some cases you should consider other ways, suck as making it constructible for example for testing purpose

Comment: I would have to ask, why service not repository? since I see them very similar.

Comment: @Lamar a Repository is often used for add a layer of abstraction over a model, a sercive is something that makes a thing, thing that is recurring on the project, and so they are used to avoid repeating code. also repository are becoming an anti pattern, they are often bad used and they just create a mess https://www.planetgeek.ch/2012/05/05/what-is-that-all-about-the-repository-anti-pattern/

Answer (score 1):

You have a fair point saying it does not look right to place query in the controller. I would offer you to have a look at the concept of Laravel repository pattern:

https://dev.to/asperbrothers/laravel-repository-pattern-how-to-use-why-it-matters-1g9d

Also, I think you could use Laravel `DB` for this kind of query without the need to write it as a raw query. I do not think there is a huge need to have a raw query here. Laravel `DB` `table()`, `select()`, `where()` and other methods should be enough.

Actually, you could potentially write this using models and their relationships, but if the query is quite slow, it is better to use query builder for better efficiency.

EDIT:

also for some specific queries which do not belong to anything I remember seeing custom trait used, could also be a solution.

Comment: Thank you! Same question as I asked the other answers: why repository rather than a service?

Comment: @Lamar I think as long as you give a good level of abstraction, any way is good. The main thing is to have the controller dumb. I think it is good to use repositories for common methods such as `search()`, `first()`, `all()`... So working with different models you will use the same method names. I think every approach is good, just you need to make it a pattern and be consistent. Even though repository is typically used with models, I do not think it is wrong to use query builder, as long as you are consistent. But I do not have too much experience, so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing my previous comment as an answer since I think its really what you are looking for:

I suggest you use a Trait to do this. The reason why is that it will keep your code clean and you'll be able to reuse this code later for other uses. A Trait is made for reusable code.

You will create a Trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;    // Optional, but you could create a namespace for all your Traits if you need others

trait MyCustomTrait
{
    public function perform(array $params) {
         $sql = "SELECT distinct product_name,product_offer.quantity, product_offer.price
                FROM product
                inner join brand on product.brand_id = brand.brand_id
                inner join brand_area on brand_area.brand_id = brand.brand_id
                inner join area on area.area_id = brand_area.area_id
                inner join product_offer on product_offer.product_id = product.product_id
                where area.area_id = :area
                and product.size_id = :size ";

         return DB::select( DB::raw($sql), $params);
    }
}
```

To use it, only write: `use MyCustomTrait` in the scope of your controller and call your function like this: `$this->perform([...])`.

Here's some links to learn more about traits:

- https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_oop_traits.asp
- https://www.develodesign.co.uk/news/laravel-traits-what-are-traits-and-how-to-create-a-laravel-trait/.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you for writing an answer, that is interesting. My question is how are Traits better than Services or Repositories, as mentioned in other replies?

Comment: A trait will be included in your class instance, so you don't need to call it statically. In your case, you will be able to write: ```$this->perform([...])```. Also, I only find it really simple to implement as it is only a class you use inside whatever class you want and then, you'll be able to call every functions in that trait like if it was in your controller.

Comment: Thank you, I really have a good appreciation of Traits, never heard of it before. But to be honest, I don't find it suitable for data retrieval. It seems to fit more like a helper code, such as validating and formatting, rather than a data access layer.

Comment: It is more like a helper yes. You use traits to insert code that you will reuse in many classes in your project. If for example, a part of your code is always the same and is doing the same work in many controllers, then a trait is really what needs to be used.